Oracle stored procedure not executing and throwing error
I have a stored procedure where I am merging two queries to get the results. But I am getting this error:

Error(331,2): PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

This is the query:
SELECT 
    jb.span_id,
    jb.maintenancezonecode,
    jbp.job_progress_id AS req_id,
    jb.reofferflag,
    modified_by AS last_update_by,
    sm.status_name,
    TO_DATE(SYSDATE) - TO_DATE(jbp.ums_group_ass_to_date) AS pending_days
FROM   
    tbl_fiber_inv_jobs jb
INNER JOIN
    tbl_fiber_inv_job_progress jbp ON jb.job_id = jbp.job_id
INNER JOIN
    tbl_fiber_inv_status_master sm ON jbp.status_id = sm.status_id
WHERE  
    jb.maintenancezonecode = pmaintzonecode
    AND ums_group_ass_to_name = pusertype
    AND jb.span_type = pspantype
    AND jbp.job_progress_flag = 1
ORDER BY 
    jbp.job_progress_id DESC

UNION ALL
  
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(TRIM(rj_span_id)) AS SPAN_ID, 
    TO_CHAR(RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE) AS MAINT_ZONE_CODE
FROM 
    NE.MV_SPAN@ne
WHERE
    LENGTH(TRIM(rj_span_id)) = 21
    AND Regexp_like (TRIM(rj_span_id),
                     'SP(N|Q|R|S).*+_(AC|BN|BS|DN|DP|ID|LA|MS|MT|MU|OG|OL|PG|RC|RG|RT|VF|VT|YH)$', 'i')
    AND NOT Regexp_like (Nvl (rj_intracity_link_id, '-'), '_(9)', 'i')
    AND inventory_status_code = 'IPL'
    AND rj_maintenance_zone_code = pmaintzonecode;


If you want to combine two query result sets with UNION ALL , they must return the same number of columns, and with the same datatype for each column

@marc_s: Except 2 columns rest 3 in first select are manually created and those are not available in second select statement. How can we update it ?

If you don't actually have any data to return from the second statement, then you'd need to return some datatype-compatible literals (and possibly just NULL) from the second statement, to get the same number of columns

ok, can u help me with some example ?

The error is because the order by is in the first branch of the union. That can't be there. You order the combined union'd result set, not the individual branch(es), and using columns included in the result set (i.e. req_id, not job_progress_id). But then you do also need to add five columns to the second branch, which could just be ,null,null,null,null,null, though you may want some dummy req_id so you can order by that.

As commented, both (actually, all) unioned selects have to have matching column list (in both number and datatype).
In your case, that would be something like
SELECT jb.span_id,
       jb.maintenancezonecode,
       jbp.job_progress_id AS req_id,
       jb.reofferflag,
       modified_by AS last_update_by,
       sm.status_name,
       TO_DATE (SYSDATE) - TO_DATE (jbp.ums_group_ass_to_date) AS pending_days
  FROM tbl_fiber_inv_jobs  jb
       INNER JOIN tbl_fiber_inv_job_progress jbp ON jb.job_id = jbp.job_id
       INNER JOIN tbl_fiber_inv_status_master sm ON jbp.status_id = sm.status_id
 WHERE     jb.maintenancezonecode = pmaintzonecode
       AND ums_group_ass_to_name = pusertype
       AND jb.span_type = pspantype
       AND jbp.job_progress_flag = 1
-- ORDER BY jbp.job_progress_id DESC
UNION ALL
SELECT TO_CHAR (TRIM (rj_span_id)) AS SPAN_ID,
       TO_CHAR (RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE) AS MAINT_ZONE_CODE,
       NULL AS req_id,
       NULL AS reofferflag,
       NULL AS last_update_by,
       NULL AS status_name,
       NULL AS pending_Days
  FROM NE.MV_SPAN@ne
 WHERE     LENGTH (TRIM (rj_span_id)) = 21
       AND REGEXP_LIKE (
              TRIM (rj_span_id),
              'SP(N|Q|R|S).*+_(AC|BN|BS|DN|DP|ID|LA|MS|MT|MU|OG|OL|PG|RC|RG|RT|VF|VT|YH)$',
              'i')
       AND NOT REGEXP_LIKE (NVL (rj_intracity_link_id, '-'), '_(9)', 'i')
       AND inventory_status_code = 'IPL'
       AND rj_maintenance_zone_code = pmaintzonecode
ORDER BY 3;

Note that you also have to remove order by from the 1st query (I commented it out) and apply sorting to the whole result set at the end of the statement.

getting error as ORA-12704: character set mismatch

Query I posted matches in number of columns. I don't know datatypes (as I don't have your tables), so - did you check whether they match? If not, do so.

even after keeping 2 columns, I am getting the same error.. why ? now this time the datatype is also same.

@hud - you're treating rj_span_id as a string, so why are you then doing to_char() for it? Are any of your columns nvarchar2 rather than varchar2? If not then maybe check if the character set on the remote and local DBs are the same - though I think that would be translated transparently.

thanks got it, need to use TO_CHAR in the second select statement

hi can u pls help on this. its almost the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78554195/subtracting-ug-length-ne-length-from-section-1-query-to-section-2-in-oracle
