Subtracting UG_LENGTH, NE_LENGTH From Section 1 query to Section 2 in Oracle
I have 2 queries where I want to subtract NE_LENGTH of 1st query to NE_LENGTH of 2nd query. Same goes for UG_LENGTH & AR_LENGTH columns respectively. I tried like below but I am getting error as Character set mismatch
(SELECT rj_span_id AS span_id,
                     rj_maintenance_zone_code                        AS
                     maint_zone_code,
                     Round(SUM(Nvl(calculated_length, 0) / 1000), 4) AS
                     ne_length,
                     Round(SUM(CASE
                                 WHEN rj_construction_methodology NOT LIKE
                                      '%AERIAL%'
                                      AND rj_construction_methodology NOT LIKE
                                          '%CLAMP%'
                                       OR rj_construction_methodology IS NULL
                               THEN
                                 Nvl(calculated_length, 0)
                                 ELSE 0
                               END) / 1000, 4)                       AS
                     ug_length,
                     Round(SUM(CASE
                                 WHEN rj_construction_methodology LIKE
                                      '%AERIAL%'
                                       OR rj_construction_methodology LIKE
                                          '%CLAMP%'
                               THEN
                                 Nvl(calculated_length, 0)
                                 ELSE 0
                               END) / 1000, 4)                       AS
                     ar_length
              FROM   ne.mv_span@ne
              WHERE  Trim(rj_span_id) = 'MHNGAJMHSNGESPN003_BS'
                     AND inventory_status_code = 'IPL' 
                     AND NOT Regexp_like (Nvl(rj_intracity_link_id, '-'), '_9',
                             'i')
                     AND rj_maintenance_zone_code = 'INMHSLPR01'
                     group by rj_span_id,
                        rj_maintenance_zone_code)

MINUS

                        
(SELECT SPAN_ID, MAINTENANCEZONECODE as MAINT_ZONE_CODE, maint_zone_ne_span_length as NE_LENGTH,
FSA_UG as UG_LENGTH, FSA_AERIAL as AR_LENGTH
from tbl_fiber_inv_jobs
where SPAN_ID = 'MHNGAJMHSNGESPN003_BS');

update
For example:-
IF NE_LENGTH value is 3 from 1st query and NE_LENGTH from second query is 2 then it should minus and show as 1

You had this error on a previous question - in one branch a column is varchar2, in the other the corresponding column is nvarchar2... probably maintenancezonecode vs rj_maintenance_zone_code?

@AlexPoole: yes, but here I want to subtract it and that's not working as expected

You're using the minus set operator (not subtraction), so the data types have to match. If you do actually mean subtracting the values then this construct is completely wrong - perhaps you want to join those two subqueries (on those two columns? in which case the data type will still need to match) and use - not minus?

@AlexPoole: yes I want to subtract it, can u suggest it how ?

Please update your question to show sample data for the results of your two queries and then show what you want the result to be when you subtract these values

A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

OK - but you haven't done what I asked: sample data for the 2 queries and then the result you want. So I'd expect to see your question updated to show 3 tables of data

Although "minus" represents subtraction, in piece of code you posted it represents as set operator which returns all rows from the 1st table that don't exist in the 2nd table. Certainly, that's just a general description and there's more behind it, such as (what you already know) the fact select statements have to have column lists that match in number and datatype.
As you literally want to subtract two numbers, that's arithmetic operation and it is the - you need. How to do that? Switch to CTEs (or inline views), join rows on common column(s) and subtract lengths.
Simplified (presuming that span_id is column you can join rows on):
with 
  first_query  as (select span_id, ug_length from ...),
  second_query as (select span_id, ne_lwngth from ...)
select a.span_id, 
       a.ug_length - b.ne_length as difference
from first_query a join second_query b on a.span_id = b.span_id;

Or, using code you posted (I didn't remove anything; looks like you might remove columns you don't actually need):
WITH 
first_query AS
(
         SELECT   rj_span_id                                      AS span_id,
                  rj_maintenance_zone_code                        AS maint_zone_code,
                  Round(SUM(Nvl(calculated_length, 0) / 1000), 4) AS ne_length,
                  Round(SUM(
                  CASE
                           WHEN rj_construction_methodology NOT LIKE '%AERIAL%'
                           AND      rj_construction_methodology NOT LIKE '%CLAMP%'
                           OR       rj_construction_methodology IS NULL THEN Nvl(calculated_length, 0)
                           ELSE 0
                  END) / 1000, 4) AS ug_length,
                  Round(SUM(
                  CASE
                           WHEN rj_construction_methodology LIKE '%AERIAL%'
                           OR       rj_construction_methodology LIKE '%CLAMP%' THEN Nvl(calculated_length, 0)
                           ELSE 0
                  END) / 1000, 4) AS ar_length
         FROM     ne.mv_span@ne
         WHERE    Trim(rj_span_id) = 'MHNGAJMHSNGESPN003_BS'
         AND      inventory_status_code = 'IPL'
         AND      NOT Regexp_like (Nvl(rj_intracity_link_id, '-'), '_9', 'i')
         AND      rj_maintenance_zone_code = 'INMHSLPR01'
         GROUP BY rj_span_id,
                  rj_maintenance_zone_code) ), 
second_query AS
(
       SELECT span_id,
              maintenancezonecode       AS maint_zone_code,
              maint_zone_ne_span_length AS ne_length,
              fsa_ug                    AS ug_length,
              fsa_aerial                AS ar_length
       FROM   tbl_fiber_inv_jobs
       WHERE  span_id = 'MHNGAJMHSNGESPN003_BS')
SELECT a.span_id,
       a.ug_length - b.ne_length as difference
FROM   first_query a join   second_query b  ON a.span_id = b.span_id; 


getting error as Error(491,45): PL/SQL: ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword

Maybe. Check line #491, position #45 in your code and fix it. What I posted shows how to do that. Adjust your code so that it reflects what I said.

yes got it.. Thanks littlefoot..!!!

Get your queries working separately and then left join them (in case that there is no matching row in second one) and do the math:
WITH    --  S a m p l e   D a t a :
    q1_data (SPAN_ID, MAINT_ZONE_CODE, NE_LENGTH, UG_LENGTH, AR_LENGTH) AS
        ( Select 1,  'MZC_A', 3, 7, 9 From Dual Union All  
          Select 2,  'MZC_B', 5, 6, 8 From Dual Union All 
          Select 3,  'MZC_C', 4, 8, 9 From Dual 
        ), 
    q2_data (SPAN_ID, MAINT_ZONE_CODE, NE_LENGTH, UG_LENGTH, AR_LENGTH) AS
        ( Select 1,  'MZC_A', 2, 3, 5 From Dual Union All
          Select 3,  'MZC_C', 1, 2, 3 From Dual         
        )

--      S Q L :
SELECT      q1.SPAN_ID, q1.MAINT_ZONE_CODE,
            q1.NE_LENGTH - Nvl(q2.NE_LENGTH, 0) "CALC_NE_LENGTH", 
            q1.UG_LENGTH - Nvl(q2.UG_LENGTH, 0) "CALC_UG_LENGTH", 
            q1.AR_LENGTH - Nvl(q2.AR_LENGTH, 0) "CALC_AR_LENGTH"
FROM        q1_data q1
LEFT JOIN   q2_data q2  ON(q2.SPAN_ID = q1.SPAN_ID)
      -- OR maybe ON(q2.SPAN_ID = q1.SPAN_ID And q2.MAINT_ZONE_CODE = q1.MAINT_ZONE_CODE)
ORDER BY    q1.SPAN_ID, q1.MAINT_ZONE_CODE

/*      R e s u l t : 
   SPAN_ID MAINT_ZONE_CODE CALC_NE_LENGTH CALC_UG_LENGTH CALC_AR_LENGTH
---------- --------------- -------------- -------------- --------------
         1 MZC_A                        1              4              4
         2 MZC_B                        5              6              8
         3 MZC_C                        3              6              6  */

Use Inner Join if there is always a match or if you want the resultset for matched rows only (in this answer SPAN_ID = 2 will be excluded from the result)
